# javascript unexpected identifier after string has been escaped?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass this escaped string to a function but keep getting an unexpected string error, with a similar string I'm getting an unexpected identifier error also. Does anyone know why this might be?

```
<a href="javascript: loadPlayer('1','Disclosure%20-%20What%27s%20In%20Your%20Head%20%28Unofficial%20Music%20Video%29%20%7C%20HD')">Video</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I think `%XX` escapes are parsed into their original characters before JavaScript gets a hold of the string to execute.

Consider something like this instead:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="loadPlayer('1','Disclosure%20.......');">
```

Comment: wow thanks so much! do you know any better ways to pass around strings with quotes in them?

Comment: You could put them in a `data-*` attribute and use `this.getAttribute("data-something")`

Comment: Yeah sounds good. As these are dynamically generated I didn't know how to link up a new jQuery event for them - I'll have to find out, thanks for your help!